# HTTP 500 error while posting using HTTP as a source for Spring XD

Tags: spring-xd

I have been trying to test a groovy filter using the code below. However, whenever I try to post using HTTP, I keep getting HTTP 500 error.

**Code:**

```
xd:>stream create --name groovyfiltertest1 --definition "http --port=9001 | filter --script=file:/Users/fkazimi/Desktop/spring-xd-1.2.0.RELEASE/xd/modules/processor/scripts/custom-filter.groovy --variables='shortstrings=false' | log" --deploy
```

**Error:**

```
xd:>http post --target http://localhost:9001 --data hello
```

> POST (text/plain;Charset=UTF-8) http://localhost:9001 hello
>
> 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
>
> 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
>
> Error sending data 'hello' to 'http://localhost:9001'

*What could be the problem and how can I fix it?*

Comment: Take a look to the container's logs and share, please, your Groovy script to be sure that there is no any issues